# Android Studio 3.1.1 update issue

Tags: android-studio

When trying to update my Android Studio 3.1.1 to the latest (3.1.4), in the update process I'm getting the following conflict:

Some conflicts were found in the installation area.
Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar

[image]

When canceling this warning tab, the update process is interrupted. Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Had a similar problem, in my case it was trying to update Android Emulator from 27.3.9 -> 27.3.10. "Solved" it by retrying the "check for updates" button, until it was successful.

Comment: It didn't work. I tried several times and the error is still prompted.